# How to rotate a PShape around its centre?

Tags: processing

The Processing handbook (second edition) has this as example 17-10:

```
PShape zig;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  zig = createShape();
  zig.beginShape();
  zig.fill(0);
  zig.noStroke();
  zig.vertex(10, 0);
  zig.vertex(100, 30);
  zig.vertex(90, 70);
  zig.vertex(100, 70);
  zig.vertex(10, 90);
  zig.vertex(50, 40);
  zig.endShape();
  zig.scale(0.7);
  zig.translate(-50, -50);
}

void draw() {
  background(204);
  shape(zig, 50, 50);
  zig.rotate(0.01);
}
```

And the images in the book that accompany this example show the shape rotating around the centre of the canvas.

However when I run that exact code, the shape rotates around the [0,0] point at the top left of canvas.

The -50, -50 translation and 50, 50 co-ordinates do seem to imply to me (based on my limited understanding) that the rotation should be centred around the [50, 50] point but this doesn't bear out when I run the code? Any ideas as to how I can get the shape to rotate around its centre?
I mean specifically using the zig.rotate() method, I know you can translate & rotate the canvas as a whole but I want to rotate specifically this shape around its centre.
Can you change a PShapes origin point after creating it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this in 3.0a10 using the default renderer. If I specify `P2D` as the renderer `size(100,100,P2D)`, the `PShape` rotates about the centre-point, as expected. Specifying P2D in version 2.2.1 also works.

So I think this looks like a bug. Maybe it's worth opening an issue on the [Processing Github](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues)?

Update: there already seems to be an [open issue for this](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2783).