# changing center of rotation for a shape in processing

Tags: processing

I am trying to rotate a vector I have created in illustrator using processing. I would like it to rotate this vector from it's center so it appears to be spinning as oppose to moving around an invisible point. Below is my attempt:

```java
PShape WOE;

void setup(){
    WOE = loadShape("WOE.svg");
    size (500, 500);
    smooth();
}

void draw(){
  background(20);
  shape(WOE, width/2, height/2, WOE.width, WOE.height); //draw shape in "center" of canvas (250, 250)
  translate(-WOE.width/2, -WOE.height/2); //move shape so that center of shape is aligned with 250, 250
  WOE.rotate(0.01);
}
```

From a strictly logical point of view this *should* work, however this results in the vector rotating around the center of the canvas, but approximately 100px away. I have tried using `shapeMode(CENTER);` but this unfortunately causes no improvement. Hope someone can help, thanks!

**For Reference**
Here is WOE.svg: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jp02yyfcrrnep93/WOE.svg?dl=0

Comment: Can you please provide the `LC.svg` and `WOE.svg` files? Also you might want to untag this as a [tag:java] question since this is specific to Processing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman see above, LC.svg is not currently being animated so please ignore it.

Comment: I'm not trying to be annoying, but we need the `.svg` file to run your code. And if we should ignore something in your code, it's probably better to just delete it. See also: [mcve].

Comment: @KevinWorkman not annoying at all, still learning proper stack overflow etiquette, thank you and see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem is that you're mixing rotating the shape and translating the entire sketch. I would try to stick with one or the other: either translate and rotate the entire sketch, or only translate and rotate the shape.

That being said, I'm not surprised this gave you trouble.

I would **expect** this to work:

```
PShape WOE;

void setup() {
  size (500, 500);

  WOE = loadShape("WOE.svg");
  WOE.translate(-WOE.width/2, -WOE.height/2);
}

void draw() {
  background(20);
  WOE.rotate(.01);
  shape(WOE, width/2, height/2);
}
```

However, this exhibits the same off-center behavior you're noticing. But if I switch to the `P2D` renderer, it works fine!

```
size (500, 500, P2D);
```

Now the shape is centered in the window and rotates around the shape's center. The difference between renderers seems buggy, but I can't find an open bug on GitHub. **Edit:** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990708/how-to-rotate-a-pshape-around-its-centre) SO question, which lead to [this](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2783) GitHub issue.

In any case, it might be easier to rotate the entire sketch instead of the shape:

```
PShape WOE;
float rotation = 0;

void setup() {
  size (500, 500);

  WOE = loadShape("WOE.svg");
  shapeMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(20);

  translate(width/2, height/2);
  rotate(rotation);
  shape(WOE);

  rotation += .01;
}
```

This code works by translating the entire sketch to the center of the window, then rotating the entire sketch, then drawing the shape. Think of this like moving the camera instead of moving the shape. If you have other stuff to draw, then you can use the `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions to isolate the transformation. This works the same in the default renderer and the `P2D` renderer.